# Send back the http request with status code and data

Tags: node.js, json, http, xmlhttprequest, postman

like in express we do res.status().send() to send the retrived data , what do we do while using just node. this is my code , what should i add

```
function getProducts() {
  http
    .get(url, (res) => {
      let body = "";
      res.on("data", (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
      });
      res.on("end", () => {
        try {
          let json = JSON.parse(body);
          console.log(json);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error.message);
        }
      });
    })
    .on("error", (error) => {
      console.error(error.message);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http.get fetches data from a remote server as said here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

The req argument in the call back function is not the req object in an express app(If you are confused)

I am assuming that you are trying to create an http server to do that look here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener

To set status code in a http server's response use https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_statuscode and to send data in response body https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback